# Drupal 7: Related Content by Title Only

Tags: drupal, view, related-content

Can anyone enlighten me how to make a "Related Content View" but **only** by titles.

I know how to do it by taxonomy terms and such I don't want that. I only want it to be related by the terms in the titles of the articles. I'm trying this for days now.

For example, lets suppose I have an article with the title: "Stackoverflow Product Tutorial by Awesomeness People"

I want to make related content View with other articles, with a contextual filter by the words "Stackoverflow", "Product", "Tutorial", "by", "Awesomeness" and "People"...

I just want related content filtered with the words from titles, to show other articles with this same words. If possible excluding words with less than 5 characters.

I think this is impossible, or at least I can not do it.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the [similar](https://drupal.org/project/similar) module for doing just this. It uses MySQLs FULLTEXT search.

There is also a comparison of other modules that offer similar functionality on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/323329).

Answer (score 0):

I am biased, but here is another module for Related Content:
https://drupal.org/project/shareaholic